# Information about floating point unit of Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1

Tags: pi-4, arm

I have this RPI board.

> Hardware  : BCM2835 Revision  : c03111 Serial     : 100000009f7a953c
> Model     : Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1

I want information about Floating point unit(FPU) it has like it supports double precision floating point or not? if yes, what instructions it uses?
Could anyone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you planning to write your own bare metal OS?

Comment: No, I want to compare FPUs of different architecture.

Comment: Pi 4 uses BCM2711, not BCM2835. Which one do you really have?

Answer (score 0):

You title says RPi m4, a bcm2711 soc with cortexA72 & vfpv4 floating point unit.
However your details are bcm2835 soc with cortexA53 & I don't find a reference to a floating point unit for this soc.

I'd be looking for an rpi4b $35 to experiment.

Good luck, morris

Comment: The question states that he already has a Pi4b.  What sort of "experiment" are you suggesting?